# Using sed to change text containing dots

Tags: sed

How can I replace website address in my files by using `sed`.
For example:

```
address = www.abc.com
```

And I want to replace it with `mail.whatever.net`.

Comment: There is no direct relationship between the two strings you mention; what are you really trying to do?  The only way to handle that replacement is to search for `www.abc.com` and replace it.  Are you worried about the search also matching `wwwXabcYcom`, which should not be changed?  If so, you would need to escape the dots: `sed 's/www\.abc\.com/mail.whatever.net/'` as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all the occurrences of `www.abc.com` by `mail.whatever.net` just use

```
sed "s/www\.abc\.com/mail.whatever.net/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you can replace the address line:

```
sed "s;^address = .*;address = mail.whatever.net;"
```